# output centered text using F-strings with dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, f-string

I want to output values from my dict using f string but if I use that code`print(f"{*excel_values['object']}")`, I have error `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here`. How can i fix this problem? UPD: I have to use f string because i want to center values using `print(f'{text: ^55}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the format method

```
print('{:^55s}'.format(*excel_values['object']))
```

By this way, you could center the text without using f-string

*Edit*
The previous answer only printed the first index of your list, if you want to print more than one index, you just have to add more placeholders.

```
>>> excel_values['object'] = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
>>> print('{} {} {}'.format(*excel_values['object']))
name1 name2 name3
```

Now, there are a lot of ways of 'spacing' this text in one line.

**Centering**

```
>>> print('{} {} {}'.format(*excel_values['object']).center(55))
                   name1 name2 name3
```

**Space between**

```
>>> print('{} {:^45} {}'.format(*excel_values['object']))
name1                     name2                     name3
```

**Space around**

```
>>> print('{:^18} {:^18} {:^18}'.format(*excel_values['object']))
      name1              name2              name3
```

**Space evenly**

```
>>> print('{:>15} {:>15} {:>15}'.format(*excel_values['object']))
          name1           name2           name3
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Using this method I get only one value from the value of the dictionary, because ma dict contain list if values 
I got ```name1``` instead of ```name1 name2 name3```

Comment: Already edited my answer to show how to print more values

Answer (score 1):

error say you can't use * expression here.
remove the star **(*)** expression

```
print(f"{excel_values['object']}")
```

Comment: You *don't* have to use an `f`-string to get data centred . You can use `format ()` or `. center()` or the `%` interpolation operator.

Comment: I should get all values from dict by key, the value is a list, so I have to use ```*```